# Getting the value of row with min(price) group by code in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure is like this:

```
country                 | price  | code
---------------------------------------
EGYPT PROPER  WHOLESALE | 0.037  | 20
EGYPT FIXED             | 0.0710 | 20
EGYPT-OTHER             | .0497  | 20
```

I have to use GROUP BY code and I want the output as:

```
country                 | price  | code
---------------------------------------
EGYPT PROPER  WHOLESALE | 0.037  | 20
```

having the minimum value of price.

And my query is:

```
select MIN(inp.price) as Price, inp.code, inp.country
from tbl_input_values as inp 
GROUP BY code
```

but i am getting the output as:

```
country         | price | code
------------------------------
EGYPT-OTHER     | .037  | 20
```

Answer (score 2):

here,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_input_values
WHERE   price = (SELECT MIN(PRICE) FROM tbl_input_values)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23ed6/1)

Comment: if they are multiple identical min(price) ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus then all of them will be shown since they have identical minimum price. right?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus is this what you are talking about? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e1f/1

Comment: Hmmm, forget about my remark, thought it wasn't wanted, but it IS probably ;)

Comment: @Raphel thanks for your reply  acctually i want to use single select, because i have records in lacs and i have just given a single code in the above example, and i have many other codes in the code column for that i have to also use group by

Comment: This gets the countries with min(price) for the whole table and not per code though.

Comment: @Dinesh but you  didn't mentioned in your problem that you need get the minimum price per code.

Answer (score 1):

This will show the rows with the minimum price, for every code:

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM yourtable
WHERE (code, price) IN (select code, min(price)
                        from yourtable
                        group by code)
```

Answer (score 1):

With multiple codes :

```
SELECT tb1.* 
FROM tbl_input_values tb1
INNER JOIN (select code, min(price) minPrice
            FROM tbl_input_values
            GROUP BY code) as a
   ON a.code = tb1.code and a.minPrice =tb1.price
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is:

```
select t.*
from t
order by price
limit 1
```

You don't need aggregation at all.